# Getting error in node modules for ag grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

When I am building the **dist** folder using `ng build` ,error of aggrid is showing in node module.

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/gridOptionsWrapper.d.ts(133,46):
>   error TS1110: Type expected.

Comment: where are you running ```ng build --prod?``` in the root directory?

Comment: @Patricio no not in root the same place where i do npm start

Comment: and what place is that one for you?

Comment: C:\Users\MU250046\Desktop\Final Code cs\service_analytics_mvp-cs>

Comment: @Patrico the place is inside cli project

Comment: can you post the whole error you see in the command line or that's all?

Comment: Yes it is the only error which i am getting @Patricio

Comment: delete entire `node_modules` folder, then do `npm i`. it'll be fixed

Comment: I am also facing this issue but the 1 answer provided did not work for me. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Faced same error after I upgraded `v19` to `v20`.

1. Delete entire `node_modules` folder
2. Do `npm install`
3. `ng build` - solved it for me.